# 13.04 GPU not playing nice with youtube

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, youtube, adobe

I am having issueswith watching YouTube videos on my laptop.
My specs are:
core 2 duo 2.3GHz
Nvidia 240M (old card)
4GB of Ram
The problem is that the video looks weird. There is some weird tearing along some corners in the video and the UI is also wrong. In windows it looks fine. I attached a picture if you look at it with a 100% zoom you can see what I mean better. I am using the 'recommended' driver from Nvidia. Also I seem to be getting a bad fps on YouTube, 11 fps on average.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ZYN.jpg]

could it be that the hardware is too old for ubuntu?

Comment: This issue could be browser related. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lag could be caused because flash isn't hardware accelerated in Chrome by default.

You should check your `about:gpu` section in Chrome. In older PC's HW Acceleration is disabled by default and you only can enable it by overriding the settings in the `about:flags`.

- Open the `about:flags` in your address bar
- Look for **Override software redendering list**
- Click "Enable"
- Restart Chrome

You can also start chrome using `chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist` but having to do so each time is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks you this worked flawlessly. I also enabled a couple of other gpu options.

Comment: glad I could help ;-)

Comment: Its good to be aware that Chrome uses its own version of flash called "PepperFlash" which is mantained by the google developers. I have had performance issues with this version of flash player before so I disabled it so that Adobe's player would be used instead. You can disable it by going into `chrome://plugins/` and disabling the flash player plugin which has the word "Pepper" in it. [This page](http://www.enounce.com/chrome-disable-pepperflash) goes into more detail about how to disable it if it ever gives you problems.